# How can the default lifecycle methods of beans be nullified?

Tags: java, spring

How can the default lifecycle methods of beans be nullified?

Please answer this question.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two new methods forSetup and forTeardown can be added to the Foo class in the following way:

```
<beans>
  <bean id="bar" init-method=”forSetup” destroy=”forTeardown”/>
</beans>
```